# rearranging order of elements within list

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am trying to rearrange the order of elements in a list.

I want to move the element at i + 1 position to the end of the list,

for len(list) - 2 times.

For example if I have

```
>>> 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15

5 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 6

5 7 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 6 8

5 7 9 11 12 13 14 15 6 8 10

5 7 9 11 13 14 15 6 8 10 12

5 7 9 11 13 15 6 8 10 12 14

5 7 9 11 13 15 8 10 12 14 6

5 7 9 11 13 15 8 12 14 6 10

5 7 9 11 13 15 8 12 6 10 14

5 7 9 11 13 15 8 12 6 14 10 # desired output
```

Below is my code, but I just cannot figure out a way to remove the i + 1th element from the list and append it at the end of the list.

The code returns an error saying that pop index out of range and its quite frustrating.

```
def rearrange(sequence):
    test_list = list(sequence)

    length = len(test_list)
    for i in range(length - 2):
        stray_element = test_list.pop(i + 1)
        test_list.append(stray_element)
```

Comment: You should make sure that your sequence is larger than 2, since you subtract 2 from the length in your routine.

Comment: @Jonah runnning this with a small sequence or even the empty list doesn't actually cause an error though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you posted (after editing it to make it return, and providing an input sequence) works fine for me and produces the desired output.

```
my_sequence = [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]

def rearrange(sequence):
    test_list = list(sequence)

    length = len(test_list)
    for i in range(length - 2):
        stray_element = test_list.pop(i + 1)
        test_list.append(stray_element)
    return test_list

print(rearrange(my_sequence))
```

outputs:

```
[5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 8, 12, 6, 14, 10]
```

(posted as an answer rather than a comment mainly because of formatting...)